# how can i remove avatar in angular 2

Tags: angular

i have the browserfile input and button to upload the logo :

```
<div class="col-md-2">
                        <form #uploadLogo="ngForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fileForm">
                            <input type="file" 
                                    class="form-control" 
                                    nodisable 
                                    name="file" 
                                    id="companyLogo"
                                    (change)="onChange($event)">
                        </form>
                        <span class="thumbnail"><img *ngIf="data.companyObj.imagePath"
                            [src]="url + '/static/logo/' + data.companyObj.imagePath" height="50px" width="250px"/></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="uploadCompanyLogo()">{{ 'BASEDATA.UPLOAD' | translate }}</button>
```

and here is the ts file :

```
public uploadCompanyLogo() {
    if(this.file == null){
        this.fileUpload.uploadFile('/company-logo', 'companyLogo').subscribe(response => {
        this.data.companyObj.imagePath = response.body.defaultLogo;
        this.sharedService.setUrl(this.data.companyObj.imagePath);
        })
```

how can i remove this with removefunction and to be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your question but if you want to remove avatar after you did your work you can set

```
data.companyObj.imagePath = null;
```

If you want to do something different please explain more.

EDIT:
After creating new delete button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="removeCompanyLogo($event)">
```

you need to make your

```
data.companyObj.imagePath = null;
```

since your image img has ngIf which is your image also created from "data.companyObj.imagePath"

```
<span class="thumbnail">
<img *ngIf="data.companyObj.imagePath [src]="url + '/static/logo/' + data.companyObj.imagePath" height="50px" width="250px"/>
</span>
```

so you need to this on your ts file

```
removeCompanyLogo (event) {
    this.data.companyObj.imagePath = null;
}
```

this will make your avatar removed.

Comment: thanks, i just want to create another button (click)="removeCompanyLogo() and than in ts file to create function
public removeCompanyLogo()